# Rspec 3.7.0 is showing Puma logs during spec suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I just upgraded Rspec from 3.6.0 to 3.7.0, and rspec-rails from 3.6.1 to 3.7.1. I'm using these libraries in a rails 5.1 app.

Since this upgrade, this is happening during my spec suite :

[image]

It's not linked to a specific spec, it's displayed in a random spot.

Looks like something changed in rspec configuration, but I can't find it in the changelog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution came from that github issue: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1897

Solution is to add the following line to rails_helper:

```
ActionDispatch::SystemTesting::Server.silence_puma = true
```

Comment: I was getting the same annoying output.

Comment: Is the underlying issue the "verbosity" of Puma restarting, or is it the fact that it is restarting at all during the test suite? If it's restarting at random times, not linked to a specific test, it seem as if silencing the output may be simply obscuring a more basic problem. What do you think?